# Changing the data (PDF) in a object

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

So I want to change the PDF shown on my site to another one when the user presses a button. Simply changing the data doesn't seem to do anything, but I think there is an error that's the issue.

**JS:**

```
function changePDF() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pdf");
  element.setAttribute("data",
  "http://www.minigal.dk/minigalnano/photos/Supported%20filetypes/PDF.pdf");
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pdf_window">
  <object id="pdf" data="http://fzs.sve-mo.ba/sites/default/files/dokumenti-vijesti/sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
  </object>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.pdf_window {
  display: block;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 56px);
  min-height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

**Question:** How do I change the PDF shown inside the object? Should I use another viewer like an iFrame to achieve this?

Snippet didn't seem to work. The PDF didn't show, but it works well on my end.

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine. Where you call `changePDF`?

Comment: Really? I call it here:
<div class="header_logout" onclick="changePDF()"> Logga ut </div>

Comment: Last questions. Do you have any javascript error in your console? Could I see the part that contains `changePDF()` (from <script> tag if possible)?

Comment: Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/EPySwtE3 I don't have a JS-file atm.

Sadly I don't know how to see console errors. I haven't used any console so far since I'm still quite new to HTML/JS. Any pointer to how to use it is appreciated.

Comment: So, it seems to be working fine in Firefox, but nothing happens in Chrome :S

Comment: In Chrome you can see the console if you push ctrl+shift+i

Comment: Okay, I see it. There are no errors though :/

Comment: Ok. It's a problem for you to use jQuery? It's simple and I'm sure that works

Comment: I have no prior knowledge of JQuery, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The problem is not in javascript in this case. I see that also in Chrome data value is changed. Mmmmm.....

Comment: Yeah, I found that too. The data is correct but it doesn't want to show.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100368/discussion-between-erikscandola-and-logic).

Answer (score 0):

Late to the Party again but since page was refreshed here is a 2022 update.

The code above was not wrong just needed to consider, every browser may handle PDF settings in so many more permutations, than you could easily allow for, hence the dozens of questions with often incorrect answers. Its a clients decision so leave the TV viewing remote control in their lap

5 ways to download a PDF in HTML, (without trying to swap them about) but here are the AEIOU most vowel methods to annoy browsers (your clients).

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><meta charset="utf-8">
<head><style>#pdf1, #pdf2, #pdf3 { width: 100%; height: 250px }</style><title>Download Vowels</title></head>

<body style="font-family: Helvetica;"><h3><center>Download to view PDF via Vowels</h3><p>


<pre style="font-family: Helvetica;">
A = Address to direct view (POST download)
      More reliable for either of 2 PDF downloads, when below methods
      (after downloading) do not support get PDF in or with your browser.
      Recommendation, right click and select Open in new Window.
</pre>
<A href="https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=2">A = "https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=2"<a><br>
<A href="https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=1">A = "https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=1"<a> 
<p>


<div class="pdf0" onclick="changePDF()">Click here to Swap those 2 PDFs if downloaded below</div><p>


<div>
E = Embedded after download
  <embed id="pdf1" title="Embed after Download" src="https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=2"/>
</div>


<div>
I = iFrame after download
  <iframe id="pdf2" title="Iframe after Download" src="https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=2">Download to Frame not working</iframe>
</div>


<div>
O = Object after download
  <object id="pdf3"  title="Object after Download" data="https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=2" type="application/pdf">Download Object Unsupported</object>
</div>


<pre>
U = User URL download
    Users may use other get and view methods such as put URI/URL ref
    direct into PDF viewer or command line `Curl -o tmp.pdf <URL> & view temp.pdf`.
</pre>


</body><script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function changePDF() {
  var urlA = "https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=2";
  var urlB = "https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=1";

  var element1 = document.getElementById("pdf1");
  element1.setAttribute('src', urlB);
  var element2 = document.getElementById("pdf2");
  element2.setAttribute('src', urlB);
  var element3 = document.getElementById("pdf3");
  element3.setAttribute('data', urlB);
};

</script></html>
```

In the plugin on the right the swap may not be exactly as expected and in a more secured browser, such as on the left, only iFrame is a viable alternative to A. `embed` and `object` are now depreciating.

[image]